# What different in the two Regular Express?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string, like this:

```js
let str = `... <!-- My -- comment
 test --> ..  <!----> ..
`;
```

And I want to get the comment part of the HTML string.

I try to use the Regular Express do this.

```js
let reg = /<!(.|\s)*?>/g

str.match(reg) // ["<!-- My -- comment↵ test -->", "<!---->"]
```

This is ok. But When I try to another Regular Express.

```
let reg = /<![.|\s]*>/g;
str.match(reg) // null
```

So what's different in two Regular Express. Why the second is fail?

Comment: The Brackets "[" and "]" will match a single character present in the set

Comment: But I add "*" character behind of “]”, It mean zero or many character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `[.|\s]` will match the literal characters `.`, `|`, or any space character.
- When you use `(.|\s)` then `.` will match any character but spaces, and `|` is the logical `or` operation.

https://regex101.com/r/xsnTbk/1

Comment: @Liam it does answer the question, "What is different in the these two Regular Express?".

Comment: Thank your answer. "." is different between [] and anywhere.